# Java thread safety and primitives

Tags: java, multithreading, primitive

I have an object which contains some primitive variables

```
public class Myobject {
    public final double d
    public long a
}
```

all those objects i store in a set which is not synchronized

```
private Set<Myobject> myset = new HashSet<>()
```

now i want to pass these objects into another thread and perform some calculations. in this thread i will only read variables "d" and "a", the varibales wont be ever changed
my question is if is thread safe to create an unmodifiable set 
    Collections.unmodifiableset(myset);
and pass it to the second thread.

Comment: Except in very special cases, thread safety is only a problem if you want to modify something while using it in multiple threads.

Comment: Well, what is your concern? If the variables will never be changed, is there any reason why `a` is not `final`? Are you overriding `equals` and `hashCode`? I would strongly recommend *not* making fields public, by the way.

Comment: It's safe if you start the other thread (call `Thread.start()`) from the same thread that initialized the set of objects, after you initialized them (since calling `Thread.start()` has a happens-before relation with the first instruction of the thread being started)

Answer (score 3):

You have two basic options to safely publish a reference to an object graph root:

- be sure that the thread which does the construction of the object graph is the one which starts (all) the child thread(s) which will use it;
- write a reference to a fully constructed object graph to a volatile variable.

Both approaches ensure a *happens-before* relationship between all inter-thread `store` actions which were executed while constructing your object graph and all inter-thread `load` actions which the other thread will be executing against the same graph. Since the first inter-thread action is guaranteed to be a `load` (reading the root reference), this implies a *happens-before* for all `store` actions of the other thread as well. So it is thread-safe to both read and write the object in the other thread—as long is it is ***the other*** thread, not *one of the other threads*.

As a standard precaution I include these quotes from the [JLS, §17.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> - A write to a volatile variable `v` (§8.3.1.4) *synchronizes-with* all subsequent reads of `v` by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).
> - An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts.

Comment: This is wrong. There are other means of safe publication.

Comment: @Raedwald Can you explain the "wrong" part? I am aware that there are other means as well, but these are fully legitimate means---recommended by the JLS itself. And I have specifically emphasized that these are two *basic* options.

Answer (score 1):

No, creating an unmodifiable colle tion is not enough. You must ensure that the thread that constructs (and/modifies) the object *safely publishes* the object to the thread that reads it. There are several ways of doing this. Some of them are rather tricky to get right. The easiest way to get it right is to have a *lock object*, and have bot threads synchronise on the lock when writing to, constructing *or* reading from it.

Comment: +1 This is correct, although it is arguable which way is the easiest. Just replacing the closing brace of the synchronized block which you mention with an assignment to the volatile variable is all it takes for the safe publication over volatile to work properly. The reading side has no restrictions whatsoever---no locks to acquire (or forget to do so).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you don't even need to create an unmodifiable set for thread safety.

If you create your set in one thread, then pass it to another thread to do something with it while not accessing it from the first thread, then there is no chance of thread-collision, since maximally one thead at a time will have access to your set.

Comment: That's incorrect. If the code in the second thread that reads these objects does not have a happens-before relationship with the code that filled the set, then the second thread may see an empty set, a set with fewer objects, a broken set, objects that are only partially initialized, etc. etc.

Comment: you have clearly not read the question - he explicitly said "i want to pass these objects" which is pretty much a guarantee that the objects are being initialized / created BEFORE they are passed since the CREATOR passes them.

Comment: @specializt That still doesn't have a happens-before relationship. Clearly people can read a question and still disagree with you.

Comment: The whole discussion is moot: you can safely publish a reference to an object graph by writing it to a volatile variable. Either way, the crux of the question is the same: is the safe publication to another thread of just a reference to an object graph root enough for thread-safety as a whole? And this question answers it properly. It *may* be improved by stressing the existence of both publishing scenarios.

Comment: @fbg if you create the objects, pass them to the runnable (constructor I'd say) and *then*start the thread you have a hb relationship. that is certainly the most obvious way how you'd do that here although certainly people are creative.

Comment: @specializt "Happens before relationship" is a term of art used in the Java Language Specification and, in books like _Java Concurrency in Practice_ (http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601/).  If you haven't studied the JLS or a book like that, then "happens before" may not mean what you think it means, and also, your Java programs may not do what you expect them to do.  In a nutshell, if a _formal_ "happens before relationship" does not exist between events, then the order in which the events _appear_ to have happened can be different for different threads.

Comment: so if someone didnt read your book that person has to have major flaws in his decade-long real-life experience AND because something doesnt have some arbitrary, formal relationship it must be inexistent of sorts? That doesnt make any sense. Im pretty sure your formal relationship is noted down as one of the key aspects of your topic - which you clearly have missed completely, now having only partial knowledge of the topic as people who write books tend to at least cover the BASIC aspects of their work. Passing invalid objects yields exceptions hence his question would be different.